# Closing Console Application After Timeout

Tags: c#, api

Situation:  I have a console application that is touching a 3rd party software (Sage).  The issue I am running into is when calling the method getCompanyAvailability(), the application times out (currently working with the creator of the API to figure out why). In the meantime, I am attempting to terminate the execution if I am waiting for a response for more than a set period of time.  The method getCompanyAvailability just returns an integer.  It seems to hit "WriteLog("Temp Message Test")" and then just sits there....  This was the code I put in place:

```
                //hung up here
                var getSageCompanyAvailability = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    return sageConnector.GetCompanyAvailability(companyName, "APIUser", "N3wPas$w0rd");
                });

                bool isCompletedSuccessfully = getSageCompanyAvailability.Wait(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(15000));
                WriteLog("Temp Message Test");
                if (isCompletedSuccessfully)
                {
                    companyAvailabilityResponse = getSageCompanyAvailability.Result;
                    WriteLog("Company Availability: " + companyAvailabilityResponse);
                }
                else
                {
                    sageConnector.DisableRequests();
                    sageConnector.DeIntializeAPI();

                    //If Succesful, still exit app. 
                    Environment.Exit(0);

                    throw new TimeoutException("Getting Company Availability Timed Out.  Ending Task...");
                }
```

Am I missing any async issues with isCompletedSuccessfully getting properly set or am I using .Wait incorrectly here?

Comment: Sounds like you could use `CancellationTokenSource` here as shown in [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/cancel-async-tasks-after-a-period-of-time)